Reused Pipes from Asbestos Tunnels in New Ventilation System – Seeking Advice
I had asbestos tunnels connected to 100mm metal pipes for self-drift ventilation. The company installing the new ventilation system agreed that all materials would be new, so they ordered new pipes and noise silencers. However, in the bedroom area, they reused the old metal pipes that were previously connected to the asbestos tunnels as exhaust air pipes, and now they are using them to supply air. This change was made without my knowledge. According to the WHO, any material previously connected to asbestos is considered contaminated. I realized they used the old pipes when I noticed that nothing had been scrapped, even though the old pipes were missing. The contractor has now acknowledged that they reused the old pipes.
The contractor has since fixed the pipes and wrapped them with insulation. Should I push them to replace the pipes with new ones? What should I do?

If the contract says all new pipes, then it does not what type of old pipes they used.  They are in the wrong.  Usually asbestos was used on the outside of pipes, so quite limited harm.  Asbestos is dangerous if disturbed/sanded/knocked around and you breath it in.

that qualifies as attempted fraud ... talk to the police

If asbestos remains intact, not broken into dust or fibers, it's not dangerous. Perhaps you can take air samples and swabs from the inside of the pipes that now supply the air you are breathing and see if there is any evidence of asbestos fibers. As with radioactivity, there's a lot of scary talk about asbestos that doesn't always measure up to the actual situation, so first it would be good to determine the actual risk here. You definitely have a right to be pissed at the contractor cutting corners without telling you though!

what is self-drift ventilation?

It sounds like you paid for new pipes that are not contaminated with asbestos, but the contractor reused old pipes contaminated with asbestos without telling you.
My recommendations:

Insist that everything be replaced with new pipes.
If air was pushed through the asbestos-contaminated pipes, and that may have affected safety, insist they perform a hazmat cleanup of the affected areas.
Find a good attorney and ask what they recommend.
Report the contractor to the appropriate licensing board as well as any safety boards/departments you deem appropriate.

